# SQL database on Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos

I have a .sql file which was exported from 2008 MS SQL server from windows computer, is there a way to import the sql file and recreate the database on a mac/osx platform? I apologize if this questions has been answered, I couldn't find a suitable response for my problem.

Thanks regardless.

Comment: SQL Server does not run on Mac OS. Fire up a Windows virtual machine using Parallels Desktop or VMWare Fusion. I hesitate to mention VirtualBox (a free alternative) because you get what you pay for - earlier this year I gave it a run and it was horribly unstable.

Comment: I have a windows machine at home, I guess I have to download the SQL server and then use my IP address to connect to it. So How would I do this? 1. Download SQL 2005 or similar. 2. Setup connection and paste the sql file. 3. Paste the files and test? (Where would I paste the files in?) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If the .sql file is actual SQL statments; create table, insert, etc, then you should be able to execute it in another RDBMS.  You will probably have to edit the SQL as it will probably have SQL Server specific syntax but the general form should be the same.

Create a DB in your target RDBMS on Mac and then execute the .sql file.

Comment: its a big file and almost impossible to retype(convert) to mysql format.

Comment: I've done this a number of times; generally you will find that there is a small number of fairly consistent changes to make.  Use search and replace to do it in a good text editor.